# How to calculate basis of kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear transformation.

The transformation and what I tried is written on the attached work page.

[image]

Is my way wrong? what is the basis of KerT?

`LinearAlgebra: S -> S` is a joke with my friends. sorry for this.

Comment: It is a good idea to have a look [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

Comment: "`LinearAlgebra: S -> S` is a joke with my friends. sorry for this." I'm more concerned about the smiley face turning into a frowny face.

Comment: After I probably failed the test I just cried. that's why I draw it.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that.

Comment: @JoeZeng Me too ........ But there's second chance. In this context, may you know about website that would help me prepare to the second final exam?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your way isn't wrong, *per se*, but it could be a great deal more efficient. The more calculations you go through, the more chances you have to make a mistake. Indeed, you have made an error. Namely, when you were at $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 2\\-1 & 1 & 3\\-1 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right]$$ and took $R_3-R_2,$ you should have gotten $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 2\\-1 & 1 & 3\\0 & -1 & -2\end{array}\right],$$ rather than $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 2\\-1 & 1 & 3\\0 & -1 & 2\end{array}\right].$$ From there, you did everything else right, but that mistake yielded an erroneous result. You've also misinterpreted this result. If you *were* able to row reduce to a matrix such as you have in the bottom-right, that would, in fact, mean, that for $T(x,y,z)$ to be null, then we need $x=0,y=0,z=0$. That is, your kernel is simply the origin, the subspace of dimension $0$. This has the empty set as a basis, **not** the set $\bigl\{(-1,1,1)\bigr\}.$

---

To be more efficient, I'd start with $R_2-2R_1$ and $R_3-3R_1$, yielding $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1 & 2 & 3 & 0\\0 & -1 & -2 & 0\\0 & -2 & -4 & 0\end{array}\right].$$ In this way we have all zeroes below the top left entry (our first non-zero leading entry). Next, I'd take $R_3-2R_2$, yielding $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1 & 2 & 3 & 0\\0 & -1 & -2 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right],$$ thus giving us all zeroes below the $-1$ in the second row (our second non-zero leading entry). Then, I'd take $-1\cdot R_2$ (so now all of our non-zero leading entries are $1$s), and finally $R_1-2R_2$, yielding $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\0 & 1 & 2 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right].$$ Our non-zero leading entries, now, are all $1$s, and have all $0$s above and below them. This is called the [reduced row echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form) of our original matrix.

Rewriting the three rows of this augmented matrix as their equivalent equations, we have: $$x-z=0$$ $$y+2z=0$$ $$0=0.$$ That last is trivial, so we have that $(x,y,z)$ is in the kernel of $T$ if and only if $x=z$ and $y=-2z$. In other words, the kernel of $T$ consists of all vectors of the form $(z,-2z,z)$ with $z$ real, or equivalently, all real scalar multiples of the vector $(1,-2,1)$. Hence, $$\bigl\{(1,-2,1)\bigr\}$$ is a basis for the kernel of $T$.

Comment: I've just freaked out when I read  your answer. 

I did the same as you, until the tester misled me and I've lost critical points. he said that there should not be trivial (zero' row) .......... 

may I ask you something? Is my the attached solution is completely bad? I mean, is there chance to get any points for this exercise?

thank you very much.

Comment: @user1798362: I have updated my answer to point out where you made your mistake, and give you a little more guidance how you may do these problems more efficiently. I know that *I* would give you partial credit for doing almost all of the work correctly, but I'd have most of the credit tied up in correctly interpreting the result, which you failed to do. Still, I'm not your grader, so I really can't say for sure how you'll do.

Comment: Thank you very much, Great explanation. I'd like to ask you a few question .. How can I send you a private message?

Comment: Follow [this link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7489/room-for-math-questions) to a chat room I just made for this purpose. You might want to open it in a different tab/window, so you can still see my post.